# Gnuplot label the points on a 'smooth unique' line

Tags: gnuplot, smoothing

I thought this would be simple to google, but I have not been able to find an answer yet:

I have the simple script:

```
plot [3:16.99][0.8:]"alltables.txt" using 1:2 smooth uniq with points
```

Where the alltables.txt is a 2-column list of numbers. The smooth uniq operation plots the moving average of my data. My question is how can I find out the coordinates of these points? And beyond that how can I label them on the plot with their coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your gnuplot version is recent enough, you should be able to

```
plot [3:16.99][0.8:]"alltables.txt" using 1:2:2 smooth uniq with labels
```